# Find and link instagram names

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, instagram

I want to make hyperlinks out of instagram usernames in a text. So all words starting with @ should be linked to instagram.com+username.. Adding a class would be nice to. I have a page containing alot of usernames.

This script only adds href and class to the current div. But it needs to include the username in the url to, and only link the word, not the entire div.

```
$(".post-text:contains('@')").addClass('arrow').attr("href", "http://instagram.com").appendTo(".post-text");
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like a very difficult thing to do...what have you attempted?

Comment: I tried to use split function and create a variable out of the @ word so that i can add it to the url. no success..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".post-text:contains('@')").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        username = $this.text().split('@')[1]; //take name after the @ symbol

    $this.addClass('arrow').data("link", "http://instagram.com/" + username);
});
```

And [here's the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gPsa/) illustrating the solution.

Comment: Big thanks! but I can't get it to work.. Am I missing something? http://jsfiddle.net/UpsQT/2/

Comment: @user681061 Divs don't have a property of `href`. Instead, you should save it into a data attribute, like `data-link`. I've gone ahead and [adjusted the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gPsa/) to suite your needs.

Comment: I want to append the url/class to the word containing @.. not the div it's in. .append(username); didn't work.. Big thanks for your help Ohgodwhy!